# @JSONField it did not work in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, fastjson

I use @JSONField annotation for pointX and pointY, I want to change pointX to point_x!
I want to pointX show like point_x! But it did not work! It always is pointX and pointY! but other field is ok!

My java bean like this!

```java
@Data
public class PointListOutput {
  
    @JSONField(name = "latest_area_point_list")
    private List<Point> latestAreaPointList;

    @Data
    public static class Point {
        @JSONField(name = "point_x")
        private Float pointX;
        @JSONField(name = "point_y")
        private Float pointY;
    }
}
```

my config

```java
@Override
protected void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);

    // create FastJson converter
    final FastJsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new FastJsonHttpMessageConverter();

    final List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);

    // create configuration class
    final FastJsonConfig config = new FastJsonConfig();
    // update filter of response
    config.setSerializerFeatures(SerializerFeature.PrettyFormat, SerializerFeature.WriteMapNullValue);
    converter.setFastJsonConfig(config);

    converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(converter);
}
```

Here is my http response, as you can see the pointX is pointX! not point_x!

```json
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "latest_area_point_list": [
                {
                    "pointX": 1.1,
                    "pointY": 1.1
                },
                {
                    "pointX": null,
                    "pointY": 1.1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this, it cause by `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties`
I used `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties`  change DAO java bean to View java bean.
My Dao java bean

```
@Data
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "xxxx")
public class PointPojo {
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "latest_area_point_list")
    private List<Point> latestAreaPointList;

    @Data
    @DynamoDBDocument
    public static class Point {
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "point_x")
        private Float pointX;
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "point_y")
        private Float pointY;
    }
}
```

And `PointPojo` did no hava `@JSONField(name = "point_x")`
after `copyProperties` the `Point` was not `PointListOutput$Point`, it was `PointPojo@Point`, and it did not hava `@JSONField(name = "point_x")`
So this is the root cause!

I use [orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/intro.html) replace `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties`, it was perfect！